# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `voted_for?' for #<User:0x007f6deb7f5368>)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I got this error when deploying my rails project to Heroku. This is my `polls/_vote_option.html.erb` file:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= content_tag(:label) do %>
        <% unless current_user.voted_for?(@poll) %>
            <%= radio_button_tag 'vote_option[id]', option.id %>
        <% end %>
        <%= option.title %>
    <% end %>
    <%= visualize_votes_for option %>
</div>
```

and here is `polls/_voting_form.html.erb` partial

```
<%= form_tag votes_path, method: :post, remote: true, id: 'voting_form' do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'poll[id]', @poll.id %>

    <%= render partial: 'polls/vote_option', collection: @poll.vote_options, as: :option %>

    <p><b>Total votes: <%= @poll.vote_summary %></b></p>

    <% if current_user.voted_for?(@poll) %>
        <p>You have already voted!</p>
    <% else %>
        <%= submit_tag 'Vote', class: 'btn btn-lg btn-primary' %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

here is `user.rb` model(`voted_for?` method was located here):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :vote_options, through: :votes
    class << self
        def from_omniauth(auth)
            uid = auth.uid
            info = auth.info.symbolize_keys!
            user = User.find_or_initialize_by(uid: uid)
            user.name = info.name
            user.image_url = info.image
            user.save!
            user
        end

        def voted_for?(poll)
            vote_options(true).any? {|v| v.poll == poll }
        end
    end
end
```

and this is `application_controller.rb` file where `current_user` method belong to:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
# encoding: utf-8
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: cookies[:user_id]) if cookies[:user_id]
  end

  helper_method :current_user
end
```

Full error's logs here:

```
2015-03-27T04:36:35.317730+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/polls/1" for 171.232.9.119 at 2015-03-27 04:36:35 +0000
2015-03-27T04:36:35.319482+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
2015-03-27T04:36:35.319468+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PollsController#show as HTML
2015-03-27T04:36:35.326980+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered polls/_vote_option.html.erb (2.4ms)
2015-03-27T04:36:35.327021+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered polls/_voting_form.html.erb (3.2ms)
2015-03-27T04:36:35.327088+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered polls/show.html.erb within layouts/application (3.4ms)
2015-03-27T04:36:35.329114+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `voted_for?' for #<User:0x007f8c17ac4220>):
2015-03-27T04:36:35.327184+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms
2015-03-27T04:36:35.329111+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-03-27T04:36:35.329122+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:         <% end %>
2015-03-27T04:36:35.329116+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <div class="form-group">
2015-03-27T04:36:35.329117+00:00 app[web.1]:     2:     <%= content_tag(:label) do %>
2015-03-27T04:36:35.329119+00:00 app[web.1]:     3:         <% unless current_user.voted_for?(@poll) %>
2015-03-27T04:36:35.329125+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/polls/_vote_option.html.erb:3:in `block in _app_views_polls__vote_option_html_erb___1797526152723756394_70119836293400'
2015-03-27T04:36:35.329120+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:             <%= radio_button_tag 'vote_option[id]', option.id %>
2015-03-27T04:36:35.329127+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/polls/_vote_option.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_polls__vote_option_html_erb___1797526152723756394_70119836293400'
2015-03-27T04:36:35.329133+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-03-27T04:36:35.329124+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:         <%= option.title %>
2015-03-27T04:36:35.329128+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/polls/_voting_form.html.erb:4:in `block in _app_views_polls__voting_form_html_erb___1028737712551643635_70119836347660'
2015-03-27T04:36:35.329130+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/polls/_voting_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_polls__voting_form_html_erb___1028737712551643635_70119836347660'
2015-03-27T04:36:35.329131+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/polls/show.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_polls_show_html_erb__3711202749271403949_70119836438440'
2015-03-27T04:36:35.329134+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

I searched google to find solution, but other solutions were quite different from what I got. I also run `heroku run rake db:migrate` and the `heroku restart`, but nothing change after that. I really confused of why `voted_for?` method was not defined(according to the error's message). So can some one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `voted_for?` is inside `class << self`, which actually creates class methods. In view you're calling `voted_for?` like this: `current_user.voted_for?(@poll)`. Where `current_user` is an object of `User` class. Hence the error.

What you need is to take that method out of the `class << self` definition:

```
class << self
    def from_omniauth(auth)
        uid = auth.uid
        info = auth.info.symbolize_keys!
        user = User.find_or_initialize_by(uid: uid)
        user.name = info.name
        user.image_url = info.image
        user.save!
        user
    end

end
def voted_for?(poll)
    vote_options(true).any? {|v| v.poll == poll }
end
```